# Link button control using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one link button in master page and one dropdown list in content page .
Can any one tell How to change the visibility of the dropdown list.

Comment: do you want to change visibility from master page? please clarify your ques.

Comment: @mahesh : Yes i change the visibility from master page

Comment: Perhaps reading this might help you http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/interacting-with-the-content-page-from-the-master-page-cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to ur masterpage.cs

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)ContentPlaceHolderID.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        ddl.Visible = false;
```